# Allow VM in gnome boxes to access webserver on host

Tags: networking, gnome, virtual-machine, gnome-boxes

I have a webserver running on my host OS and I want to access it from a windows VM running in gnome boxes. The VM has internet access but it does not seem to be able to access anything on the local network by local IP address. There seems to be no UI for changing network settings. Is there any way to change the network configuration to allow accessing local devices on the network?

Answer (score 1):

GNOME Boxes uses QEMU under the hood. By default, it "emulates" a network for the guest, where it simply "passes through" on the guest the same Internet access capabilities that the host has. The host itself can be accessed by the IP address of the default gateway, which is 10.0.2.2 by default. The guest should be able to access the resources of the LAN, which the host is connected to, if the host itself can access them.

Most likely, you have your webserver configured so that you cannot access the webserver from the host by the host's IP address in the LAN, but you can access it by localhost at 127.0.0.1. If so, you should be able to access that webserver by 10.0.2.2 in the guest, but you will not be able to access the host from the guest by the host's IP address in the host's LAN because the host itself cannot do it.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, gnome-boxes (like the majority of "gnome" software) is very limited and won't allow for any customisation. Your best bet would be using KVM directly (which is what gnome-boxes is a primitive GUI for) or using other solutions like Virtualbox, etc.